# facebook logout is not working in ios 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, ios9

i am not able to logout while logged using Facebook SDK. Could you please check the following code :

```
self.login =[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
[self.login logOut];
```

Comment: When i am trying to logout using above code not able to logout & next time while i am trying to login then i am getting one message 
i.e "You have already authorized app ".
Please kindly suggest me.

Comment: Please kindly help me about this issue...

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution when you are using FBSDKLoginButton dont clear anything before logging out :

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error{
    if (!error) {
        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture.type(large), email, name, id"}]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     //Perform your logic & then logout using below code
                     FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
                     [loginManager logOut];
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried above code on logout but it is not working ....since i am not able to logout.

Answer (score 0):

check you are log in In Safari browser, Facebook can not responsible to do Logout in Safari browser.

```
self.login =[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
[self.login logOut];
```

`logout` method will just close the session of Facebook in iOS Application.
so just logout from safari browser and then check whether it works or not.

Comment: Could you please let me know another solution when user clicked on Logout button then it should be logout like Google....

Comment: This is Manually solution , i need as dynamically like google logout.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 keys are SSO and Safari. Facebook poorly documents the Facebook Login process. You may want to turn off SSO. This is on the Facebook Developer site, where your app is registered, under Settings. But more importantly is I had to change the behavior of the FBLoginManager to use UIWebView and not Safari. I did this with the following snippet:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginMgr = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
loginMgr.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

If you use the default behaviors it will manage logouts through the Facebook App or the browser Safari, and not directly from the App. The FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb is to use iOS UIWebView in a popup. This works perfectly, and credentials are required each time after a logout.